# Database import constraint fail

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql

I've got a working Magento website hosted on a development server but I've decided to take a local copy to make it easier to work on.

I've downloaded the source files and imported the database. All looks to be working perfectly, I can see all of my products and I can't see any problems - but during this import, I noticed this error:

```
My.Name@NETWORK c:\xampp\htdocs\website
# mysql -u root database < database.sql
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 415010: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`#sql-be4_32`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE )
```

Will this error have stopped certain data from being imported. Everything at the moment looks fine and ideally I would like to continue and ignore the error - but I don't want it to bite me in days/weeks to come!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are trying to add a record into `catalog_eav_attribut`e, but you
>   do not have a corresponding record in `eav_attribute` that matches on
>   `attribute_id`
>
> If you are also inserting bulk data into `eav_attribute`, I would
>   recommend doing that first, and then the data would be in the table
>   before the foreign key on `catalog_eav_attribute` needed to reference
>   it.
>
> This [article](http://www.stetsenko.net/2008/10/mysql-how-to-ignore-checking-of-foreign-key-constraints-for-innodb-tables/) discusses how you can use:
>
> `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
>   --Do your update here 
>   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`
>
> If you cannot change the order that you are inserting data. You just have to make
>   sure your data follows the Foreign Keys once everything has been
>   inserted into the database, before you can re-enable the
>   `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306636

Comment: So I should edit my .sql file, adding `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` at the start and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` at the end - then reupload my file?

Comment: Yea, just be aware the reason the reason for the foreign key check, is data integrity so some data may be missing and/or duplicated. More details: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp